# How to create exception with specific fields?

Tags: java, exception

I have an exception class as :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductsException extends RuntimeException {

    private MyError error;

    public ProductsException(Exception e) {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

```
public class MyError {
    private final String errorCode;
    private final String message;
    private final String moreInfo;
    private final List<Errors> errors;


    public MyError(String errorCode, String message, String moreInfo, List<Errors> errors) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.message = message;
        this.moreInfo = moreInfo;
        this.errors = errors;
    }
```

This exception is being thrown from inside the service class but my client expects exception as :

```
{
    "personId" : "1",
    "code" : "1",
    "debugger" : "[
        //List
    ]"
    
}
```

So I created a new class as

```
@Builder
public class CustomException extends ProductsException {

    private final String personId;
    private final String code;
    private final List<String> debugger;

}
```

And in the controller :

```
catch(ProductsException e) {
  throw CustomException.builder()
    .code(e.getErrorCode())
    .debugger(List.of(e.getError().getMessage()))
    .build();
}
```

This does not seem to work and I am getting uncaught exception.
I am suspecting that I need to pass these fields in the constructor but not sure what needs to be done exactly.

Even if I do `public class CustomException extends RuntimeException`
how can I pass all these fields to `super()` ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the additional fields to the superclass. Instead your class must manage them itself. Example:

```
public class CustomException extends ProductsException {

    private final String personId;
    private final String code;
    private final List<String> debugger;

    public CustomException(String personId, String code, List<String> debugger) {
        super();
        this.personId = personId;
        this.code = code;
        this.debugger = debugger;
    }

    public CustomException(String personId, String code, List<String> debugger, Exception cause) {
        super(cause);
        this.personId = personId;
        this.code = code;
        this.debugger = debugger;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Failed at " + personId + ", " + code + ", " + debugger;
    }

}
```

Change getMessage() to format the message to your needs. Or add getter functions so some other code part can take over formatting as needed, e.g. it would be different for your customer than for the logfile.

I cannot tell why you get uncaught exceptions. There may be something missing in your try/catch blocks but you show where you throw, not where you catch.